# Hybrid bluetooth adapter not detected linux

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, bluetooth, arch-linux

I am using Arch linux currently, and I cannot use my bluetooth driver in it. My PC is a laptop, DELL Inspiron n4030 i3-380m and it has a hybrid BROADCOM 4313 Wifi and bluetooth card inbuilt. The wifi is working fine, but there is no sign that bluetooth exist.

I have bluez and blueman installed.

The driver that I am using for my wifi is `b43`

`sudo lspci -vnn -d 14e4:`

```
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300 [1028:0010]
    Physical Slot: 0-1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fbb00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-78-ff-ff-4a-cc-af
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

When I start the bluetooth with
`sudo modprobe btusb; systemctl start bluetooth`
`sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[ 1334.131956] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 1334.132020] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[ 1334.132022] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1334.132029] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1334.132032] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1334.132038] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 1342.140875] audit: type=1130 audit(1632067873.984:152): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=bluetooth comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[ 1342.189409] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 1342.189419] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 1342.189430] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`sudo lsmod | grep bluetooth`

```
bluetooth             729088  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 32768  10 bluetooth,dell_laptop,brcmsmac,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

`sudo rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I do `bluetoothctl`

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

If you need more log then I could provide.
And yes, the bluetooth module works, as I had used it on ubuntu (somehow, that I dont remember) and windows10 with lenovo drivers.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0000:0538   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0c45:6488 Microdia Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_0.3M
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Bluetooth is connected using USB. Check whether `lsusb` shows something. The Bluetooth device may also need firmware.

Comment: No, bluetooth is inbuilt

Comment: You misunderstand. The Mini-PCIe or M2 socket also has USB connectivity. That's how the Bluetooth part of the WiFi card connects to the host. Even if the device is internal.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information there. This way, you have proper formatting at your disposal.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)

Comment: Do this help to identify the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129776/discussion-between-afroz-alam-and-daniel-b).